# Connect to host computer from Virtual PC 2007

Tags: networking, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am having trouble using my guest (Windows XP SP3) to communicate over TCP/IP to the host computer (Windows 7) using Virtual PC 2007. I have WAMPServer running on my host, and want to be able to access the websites on there from my guest OS.

What do I do to make this work? What is the IP address of the host computer when using Shared Networking?

As far as I can tell "Internal Networking" won't work, because that only allows communication between the guests, not between a guest and the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For it to work with shared networking mode, leave the guest's IP settings to be autoconfigured by DHCP. You should be able to access the site by the IP returned in `ipconfig` (on the host). NAT and Bridged should also work, even with static addressing (as long as it's done correctly).

Comment: Need to use IP addresses because Win7 and XP don't normally discover each other automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your NIC will be listed on the *Network Adapter* setting on Virtual PC, select that one (and disable all other adapters)

For the guest machine, specify an IP address at the same subnet as the host (ie: if your host IP is 192.168.1.5, the guest must be 192.168.1.x),the Gateway and DNS address must be the same as on the host.

Make sure the **Virtual Machine Network Service** is listed and checked on the host NIC, and you have installed the **Virtual Machine Additions**.

should work.

Comment: I agree to the Network Adapter setting, but prefer John's recommendation for using DHCP.